# I'm struggling with a particle motion with one degree of freedom question.

Tags: classical-mechanics, arc-length

**Q)** Given that y(x) = log(1 + cos x) on the interval (0, π)

Taking signed arclength s=0 at x=0 show that:

x(s) = 4arctan(tanh(s/4))

**Attempt)**

I tried using (ds/dx)^2= 1 + (dy/dx)^2 rule to get dx/ds = (cosx+1)/root(2cosx+2)

Then integrating dx/ds gives me x(s) =  2sin(x/2)+ c

Im really stuck on the next step on what to do next to get x(s) = 4arctan(tanh(s/4)) and how do I calculate y(s) from this?

Comment: If there's anything wrong with my question could I get a suggestion to somehow improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a bit obscure. Recalling what you did, for the sake of public understanding:

$$\ell = \frac{\text{d}s}{\text{d}x} = \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}\right)^2}$$

$$y(x) = \ln(1 + \cos(x)) \longrightarrow 1 + \left(\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}\right)^2 = \frac{2}{1 + \cos(x)}$$

$$s(x) = \int \sqrt{\frac{2}{1 + \cos(x)}}\ \text{d}x = 2 \ \text{arctanh}\left(\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right) + C$$

On the other hand we have too:

$$\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}s} = \frac{1}{\frac{\text{d}s}{\text{d}x}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{1 + \cos(x)}}} = \cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$

Yet from here I cannot understand the statement of the problem and most of all how it gets to that result. Do you have a copy of the homework, for even finding the inverse function I do not think there is a way to come to that result...

Comment: You've shown $x=2\arcsin\tanh(s/2)$, which can be rewritten as $4\arctan\tanh(s/4)$ because [both are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function#Some_identities) $2\operatorname{gd}(s/2)$.

Comment: @J.G. And this makes me wonder "why the heck have I always avoided to learn about Gudermannian function??" - Well I believe it's time to remedy...

Comment: You're both legends! Thank you so much.